# Intel Wireless Dual Band AC-3160+Ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: intel-wireless

I have downloaded iwlwifi-3160-ucode firmware to /lib/firmware, but don't know what to do next. The wireless connection starts, then stops to ask for password every 5 seconds.

```
lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 65 
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M] 
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] 
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64] 
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: i915 

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 66 
    Memory at f7d14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel 

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59 
    Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd 

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 62 
    Memory at f7d1d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me 

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64 
    Memory at f7d10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel 

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0 
    Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0 
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff 
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI]) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23 
    Memory at f7d1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci 

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich 

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0]) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60 
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8] 
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4] 
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8] 
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4] 
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32] 
    Memory at f7d1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: ahci 

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device b213 
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 3 
    Memory at f7d19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256] 
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32] 

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83) 
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 63 
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi 

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07) 
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device 8168 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61 
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256] 
    Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K] 
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: r8169 

nm-tool

 NetworkManager Tool 

State: connected (global) 

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] ------------------------------------------- 
  Type:              Wired 
  Driver:            r8169 
  State:             connected 
  Default:           yes 
  HW Address:        00:01:2E:56:0E:E8 

  Capabilities: 
    Carrier Detect:  yes 
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s 

  Wired Properties 
    Carrier:         on 

  IPv4 Settings: 
    Address:         192.168.2.17 
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0) 
    Gateway:         192.168.2.1 

    DNS:             192.168.2.1 


- Device: wlan0 ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Type:              802.11 WiFi 
  Driver:            iwlwifi 
  State:             disconnected 
  Default:           no 
  HW Address:        A0:88:69:35:F7:28 

  Capabilities: 

  Wireless Properties 
    WEP Encryption:  yes 
    WPA Encryption:  yes 
    WPA2 Encryption: yes 

  Wireless Access Points 
    TVName1: Infra, 30:60:23:16:D4:F5, Freq 5260 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 WPA2 
    Name2:         Infra, 18:62:2C:E0:9E:E3, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 89 WPA2
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, same lspci -v output, but only with some routers. For now, I carry a USB wifi adapter with me.

Answer (score 2):

See this post, it should help...

Intel AC-3160 Firmware Update fixes Bluetooth:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214075

good luck!